# How sum a range of values when the criterion depends on multiple values spread along different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

Suppose we have the following table in Google Sheets:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | green apple | apple | =SUMIFS(A:A, B:B,"*" & D1 & "*", C:C,"*"&D1&"*") |
| 1 | Orange |  | banana | =SUMIFS(A:A, B:B,"*" & D2 & "*", C:C, "*" & D2 & "*") |
| 20 | a | red apple |  |  |
| 1 | banana |  |  |  |
| 1 | kiwi |  |  |  |
| 1 | Banana |  |  |  |

Then E1 == 0 and E2 == 2. This is because SUMIFS sums the values of B column if ALL the criteria for all ranges are TRUE, this is equivalent to say that SUMIFS joins all criteria with an AND (logical) operator.
What I need is the same SUMIFS operation but with an OR operator so that E1 == 21.

One solution is to concatenate B and C values in F column and then simply use this formula
`=SUMIF(F:F, "\*" & D1 & "\*", B:B)`

Is there another way to do this without having to create another column?

Since someone edited the tags, the answer can be written for Google Sheets, Excel, LibreOffice and similar apps. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Why not `=SUMIF(B:B;"*"&D1&"*";A:A)+SUMIF(C:C;"*"&D1&"*";A:A)`?

Comment: That sums twice, then I don't have the correct number

Answer (score 0):

If your real application only needs to find *any* items from D:D in *either* of only two columns and then return one final total, you can use this:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B:B&"~"&C:C),JOIN("|",FILTER(LOWER(D:D),D:D<>""))))))))`

If your real application needs to find *any* items from D:D in more that two columns and then return one final total, you can either continue to join columns like this — `B:B&"~"&C:C` — or use a formula like this:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:C),,COLUMNS(B:C)))),JOIN("|",FILTER(LOWER(D:D),D:D<>""))))))))`

If you need a per-item count of the strings in D:D if they appear any number of times in other columns, try this:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(TRIM(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(D:D,D:D<>"")),LOWER(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(B:C),,COLUMNS(B:C))))))),,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(LOWER(D:D),D:D<>""))&"~"&A:A)),"~"),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) ''")),"WHERE Col2 Is Not Null"))`

Answer (score 0):

If there will only ever be 2 columns to consider, then it makes sense to go with JohnSUN's suggestion from the comments.

Otherwise:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N(MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,B$1:C$6))),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B$1:C$6)^0))>0),A$1:A$6)`

The range referenced (`B$1:C$6`) can be extended to one comprising as many columns as desired, though bear in mind that, having switched from a `SUMIF` set-up to a `SUMPRODUCT` one, you would be strongly advised to not use entire column references (at least in Excel this is the case; not sure about Sheets).